# Missing number in array Python Practise Sheet Question

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a student and learning data structures and algorithms. I am unable to solve or short out this GFG question.

**Missing number in array**
[image]

Given an array of size N-1 such that it only contains distinct integers in the range of 1 to N. Find the missing element.

I tried this code but it is not working for all cases.

```
def MissingNumber(self,array,n):
        
        missingNumber = 0
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if array[i] !=i+1:
                missingNumber = i+1
        
        return missingNumber


Input:
N = 5
A[] = {1,2,3,5}
Output: 4
```

Please help me out with the code of the best complexity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot to add code that you have tried

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner and I dont get the logic to code the program. I have added the ques link to go through

Comment: so you can't demonstrate *any* effort towards solving this problem yourself?

Comment: sounds to me like you just want us to do this problem for you, which is a bit unfair to ask to others.

Comment: I was trying to work it out using for loop and comparing all the elements with their indexes. But that was a brute force way with worst time complexity.

Comment: you could always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73733130/edit) the question to mention what you've tried so far.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks! I am just new to this platform. Also, got the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know whether it is the best way to solve this question but here is my code with the O(N) time complexity and O(1) space complexity respectively. Here is my code. Hope this helps you out.

```
def MissingNumber(self,array,n):
        # The expected sum of the complete array should be ...

        expectedSum = (n*(n+1)) //2
        
        total = 0
        
        for i in array:
            total+=i

        # check the difference between expected sum and actual sum of an array that's the missing number in an array.

        return expectedSum-total
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. All test cases are working. But i have one doubt. Can you please tell me how you get this logic behind?

Comment: No issue. It is the mathematics logic like if you have n numbers then the total sum of n numbers will be (n*(n+1)) / 2  

Now when you get the total sum of n numbers. You will run a for loop to get the actual sum of the array. Now when you will difference both the sum you will get the missing number in the array. Try it with pen and paper once. You will get the logic.

Comment: The explanation was really good. Thank you very much. I am just a beginner I cant figure out the logic behind. So sorry for that. Really appreciated!